# Chrome debugger permanently breaks on point that has no breakpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I run node with --inspect-brk it first breaks on line 1 (as expected because I added -brk). Then it breaks in a file in node_modules on line 126 where there is no breakpoint, debugger statement or error.

I rebooted the computer but it keeps doing this, I tried settings -> restore defaults and reload in the dev tools but it keeps doing this. In the dev tools I tried right clicking line 126 and choose "never pause here" and it puts an orange arrow at line 125 so I tried the same at line 127 and it puts the orange arrow at 127 but still breaks on 126.

I'm close to tossing the laptop out of the window and try it on another one as this irritates me to no end but the problem is probably with chrome dev tools. I am using Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) on mac os catalina 10.15.2

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include any code/screenshots of the issue?

Comment: @Nisarg Was caused because I put a debugger statement in the file but what the debugger shows is the result of source map so that's why it didn't show the debugger statement but did break there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I got into this situation. I edited the file in node_modules and put a debugger statement in node_modules/package/**dist**/theFile.js to figure out how to use that package.

When running the code it shows me it breaks on node_modules/package/**src**/theFile.js and does not show me the debugger because node_modules/package/**src**/theFile.js does not exist but because node_modules/package/**dist**/theFile.js.**map** does exist it shows a non existing file in debugger and does not show the debugger statement because the source map was not re created.